# Can't require authentication for a specific endpoint using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to require authentication for my endpoints that start with "/chat/..." (on GET requisitions). I have done some basic configuration but it doesn't seem to be working. Even after authenticating a user and using its generated JWT Token, Postman still returns code 403 (Forbidden) for me. What could I be doing wrong?

My SecurityConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_GET = {
            "/usuarios/**",
    };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/login/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_GET).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/chat/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil));
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

My ChatController class:

```
import com.example.chatonline.domain.Mensagem;
import com.example.chatonline.domain.Usuario;
import com.example.chatonline.services.ChatService;
import com.example.chatonline.services.UsuarioService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/chat")
public class ChatController {

    @Autowired
    private ChatService chatService;

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @GetMapping(value = "/usuarios")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>> findOnlineUsers(){
        List<Usuario> usuarios = usuarioService.findByOnlineUsers();

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(usuarios);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @GetMapping(value = "/mensagens")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Mensagem>> findMessages(){
        List<Mensagem> obj = chatService.findMessages();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> insertMessage(@RequestBody Mensagem obj){
        obj = chatService.insertMessage(obj);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mensagens/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteMessage(@PathVariable Integer id){
        chatService.deleteMessage(id);

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex. I think this would require contents of JwtAuthenticationFilter and JWTUtil also to be able to decide what is wrong.

Comment: Note that Spring Security has build in support for JWT authentication, so there is no need to create your own. You can check out a sample [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) .